# Given any Cauchy Sequence $S = (a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is Bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, cauchy-sequences

I am required to prove the following Lemma. What follows is my attempt can someone please verify that it is correct.

**Please consider the following Definitions and Lemma  prior to reading the Argument.**

> **Definition.** A Sequence $(a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ of rational numbers is eventually $\epsilon$ steady if and only if there exists an $N\in\mathbf{N}$ such that $d(a_j,a_k) = |a_j-a_k|\leq \epsilon$ for all $i,j\ge N$.
>
> **Definition.** A Sequence $(a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ of rational numbers is a Cauchy Sequence if it is eventually $\epsilon$ steady for all $\epsilon>0$.
>
> **Lemma. $5.1.14$** Every finite sequence of rational numbers $(a_n)_{n=0}^{m}$ is bounded.

**MY ATTEMPT:**

> **Lemma** **$5.1.15$** (Cauchy sequences are bounded). Every Cauchy
> sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded.

**Proof.** Let $S = (a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be an arbitrary cauchy sequence. From Definition $S$ is eventually $\epsilon$ steady for every $\epsilon>0$, then in particular for $\epsilon = 1$ we have an $N\in\mathbf{N}$ $\text{s.t.}$ $\forall j\ge N\forall k\ge N(|a_j-a_k|\leq1)$. Consequently we may split the $S$ $\text{s.t.}$ $S = (a_n)_{n=0}^{N-1}+(a_n)_{n=N}^{\infty}$.

For $P = (a_n)_{n=0}^{N-1}$ we have a bound $M$ from Lemma **$5.1.14$** and for $Q = (a_n)_{n=N}^{\infty}$ we know that $|a_j-a_N|\leq 1$ for an arbitrary $j\ge N$. Equivalently $-1+a_N\leq a_j\leq 1+a_N$. Now we know from proposition **$4.3.3$** that $-|a_N|\leq a_N\leq |a_N|$ from which we may deduce that $-|a_N|-1\leq a_N-1$ and $a_N+1\leq |a_N|+1$ consequently $-1-|a_N|\leq a_j\leq 1+|a_N|$ and thus $|a_j|\leq |a_N|+1$.

Now let $H = M+|a_N|+1$ and let $i\in\mathbf{N}$. If $1\leq i\leq N$ then $|a_i|\leq M\leq M+|a_N|+1 = H$ and similarly for $i\ge N$ we have $|a_i|\leq |a_N|+1\leq M+|a_N|+1 = H$. Therefore for all $i\in\mathbf{N}$ we have $|a_i|\leq H$ thus $S$ is bounded.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Sure, looks fine. Out of curiosity why is everything only defined for the rationals?

Comment: @bitesizebo I am using Terence Tao's Analysis Volume One. At this stage he is trying to contruct real numbers as limits of rational sequences.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.